# Windows heap manager and heap segments

Tags: c++, c, windows, internals

I found the following sentence in a book :

> Whenever the heap manager runs out of committed space in the heap segment, it
>   explicitly commits more memory and divides the newly committed space into blocks
>   as more and more allocations are requested

Does this mean when a block is allocated in the segment the virtual memory used by the user and the metadata isn't considered committed anymore ?

Comment: Huh? Your sentence kind of fell apart at the end.

Comment: If you want to know how Windows deals with ram watch [the talk by Mark Russinovich](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/TechEd/NorthAmerica/2011/WCL405)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is from the advanced windows debugging book I take it, not sure what you mean as you get kind of vague towards the end, however what it basically means is as follows:

When you allocate heap space the contents of the heap are not necessarily pre-determined, so you can use that allocated space as you see fit:  for example, I allocate 1 megabyte of heap memory, and I then decide to populate that space with only 512k or data, that would mean I have committed half of my allocated heap, leaving a further 512k free.  That memory will still show as being utilised to the OS because I have explicitly set the heap allocation to 1024k, however next time I use that same space I could use more or less than the 512k I utilised last time, up to the amount I have allocated for use.  The amount you use at a given point is the commit, the amount you have set aside is the allocation.

This is all much much simplified, and I would recommend reading such sources as:

- [stack-memory-vs-heap-memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5836309/stack-memory-vs-heap-memory) from here
- [the-stack-and-the-heap](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/79-the-stack-and-the-heap/) from learn CPP
- [Memory_Stack_vs_Heap](http://gribblelab.org/CBootcamp/7_Memory_Stack_vs_Heap.html) from CBootCamp

As good sources to get you started on memory and its usage in C++.

If there is anything specific or more detail you can think of (your question is a bit unclear) then let me know and I will get back to you as soon as possible.

Answer (score 0):

No. Allocated blocks are part of committed memory.