# C++ object, difference between dynamic and static

Tags: c++

What is the difference between creating class object in the two following ways:

```
class cat 
{
  private: 
     int age; 
  public: 
     cat(); 
}; 


int main(void) 
{
  cat object; // static object 
  cat *pointer = new cat(); // dynamic object 
}
```

Comment: The keywords here are heap and stack: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5836309/stack-memory-vs-heap-memory https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79923/what-and-where-are-the-stack-and-heap

Comment: The first one isn't static, it's automatic.

Answer (score 5):

The first one is declaring a static variable (usually on the stack*) that will die at the end of the code block in which it is defined.

The second one is dynamically allocating a variable (usually on the heap*) which means that you are the one that can decide where to deallocate it with delete[] (and yes you should remember to do it).