# Run time error on large array sizes in C/C++

Tags: c++, c, arrays

I tried to do this declare array (size=1,000,000) in C++ it give me a run time error.

```
unsigned long long a[1000000];
```

but it allows this(size=100,000)

```
unsigned long long a[100000];
```

again it give run time error for following

```
  unsigned long long a[100000];
  unsigned long long b[100000];
```

but i can do same thing as follows

```
unsigned long long* a = new unsigned long long[1000000];
```

can any one please explain the reason for this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In C++, when you're doing this:

```
unsigned long long a[100000];
```

It allocates the memory from the stack. Stack memory is limited so you can't do too big allocations.

When you do this:

```
unsigned long long* a = new unsigned long long[1000000];
```

It allocates the memory from the heap. Heap allocations can be big.

More information about stack and heap memory is in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5836309/stack-memory-vs-heap-memory) Stack Overflow post.

Comment: Your initial statement is true for local variables only.