# C++ large array of vectors

Tags: c++, arrays, vector

I'm having some troubles with a large array of vectors in C++. 
Basicaly I wan't an array of 2 millions elements, and each elements is a `vector<int>` (It's for building an adjacency list).

So when I do `vector<int> myList[10]` it works great, but when i do `vector<int> myList[2000000]` it does not work and I don't know why.

I tried to do `unsigned long int var = 2000000; vector<int> myList[var];` but still the same error. (I don't know what is the error, my program just crash)

If you have any idea,

Thanks

Comment: Are you trying to declare this array as a local variable?

Comment: Maybe helpful - change `var` to a `const unsigned long int` - variable length arrays are a compiler extension, not part of C++. Adding the `const` makes it "correct" in the sense that the array length is compile-time determined, which removes a possible source of suspicious behaviour.

Comment: Use a vector of vectors. Trying to declare an array of that size on the stack is very likely to fail, as you've seen. You could also make it a global or static if you wish. *shrug*

Comment: Thanks. I will try with a vector of vector but i don't understand, 2 millions times 24B is not that large for the memory :/

Comment: `sizeof(vector)` is probably somewhere around 24 bytes. 2 million of those is somewhere around 45 megabytes. The default stack size is generally much smaller than that, so if you try to make it a local variable you have a stack overflow. On the heap, that's not so much.

Answer (score 5):

There's a big difference between [heap and stack memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5836309/stack-memory-vs-heap-memory). The heap is the nice big space where you can dynamically allocate gigabytes of memory - the stack is much more constrained in terms of allocation size (and is determined at compile time).

If defining a local variable, that means it lives on the stack (like your array). With 2 million elements, that's at least 2MB being allocated (or assuming ~24B of stack usage per vector, more like 48MB), which is quite a lot for the stack, and likely causes the crash. Dynamically allocating an array of `vector`s (or preferably just allocating a `vector` of `vector`s) ensures that the bulk of the memory is being allocated from the heap, which might prevent this crash.

You can also increase the size of the stack using [compiler flags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2275550/change-stack-size-for-a-c-application-in-linux-during-compilation-with-gnu-com), but that's generally not preferable to just dynamic allocation.

Comment: Thanks hnefatl, yeap with a vector of vector it works but i still don't understand why an array is in the stack and a dynamic allocating is on the heap ? But thanks the problem is solved !

Comment: @Charles C++ defaults to locally declared variables being on the stack. If you want dynamic memory, you can allocate it on the heap but the pointers to the memory are on the stack. It's just the way things are in C++. `vector`s internally allocate memory off the heap, whereas arrays by nature are allocated on the stack (which is why their size has to be given at compile time).

Comment: @hnefatl: It’s not that arrays go on the stack, it’s that local variables (only their static footprint!) do.

Comment: @hnefatl: `new int[2]` makes an array on the heap.  `vector<int> foo(2);` puts `foo` on the stack, but the `int`s are still on the heap.  Does that help?

Answer (score -2):

[This is helpfull](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=5&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjay8yD6YLXAhXJxRQKHfV8COUQFgg7MAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F3113668%2Flocation-of-pointers-and-global-variables-in-c&usg=AOvVaw1ZSnsizxc3w8r4-f5Xb2Cp)

Dynamically allocate memory for `my_List`. or

Declare your array of vector of int's(`my_List`) as a global variable and size a `const. Thier storage locations are by design big enough to allocate such large mermory size.

For local variable, the stack segment might be to small to allocate 2e6*24B.

Comment: Works, but bad advice. No need to go global for this. `static` would be better, but `vector` of `vector`s gets the job done without any fuss.

Comment: @user4581301 There are multiple ways of doing the same thing. considering all the options is not a bad idea.

Comment: I can kill a wart on my foot by chopping off my leg. This does not make it an option worth considering.