# Is the pointer holding dynamic variable in the stack or heap?

Tags: c++

I want to get something clear that I found most sources so confusing.

For example,

```
int *a=new int;
```

Is "a" in stack or heap, and what about "*a"? Most sources I found only refer to heap, I really need an extremely concrete answer. I would be really grateful.

Comment: `a` on stack, `*a` on heap.

Comment: @GauravSehgal Only for architectures that have a stack or a heap.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5836309/stack-memory-vs-heap-memory or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79923/what-and-where-are-the-stack-and-heap

Comment: @JerryJeremiah like?

Comment: You'll need to show a bit more code to determine where `a` is. It could be a global variable too.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`a` is in the stack. When the scope of `a` ends, `a` is not usable.

`*a` is in the heap.  Even after the scope of `a` ends, the object that `a` points to continues to live unless the memory is deallocated before that.

Comment: What if the global `new` has been overloaded to get memory and construct the object in a different place to the heap?

Answer (score 0):

Apart from where on the `stack` or `heap`, you should think about it in a c++ way, and that is by considering its [storage duration.](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration) For example, the global `new` operator can be overloaded to do whatever. Maybe the object you are being returned is not on the heap or the stack, but is created in global or some specific device memory.

`a` has *automatic* storage duration. Which means:

> The storage for the object is allocated at the beginning of the enclosing code block and deallocated at the end.

The object created by `new int` has *dynamic* storage duration:

> The storage for the object is allocated and deallocated per request by using dynamic memory allocation functions.